# What is the convergence or divergence of $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}\left(\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{n}\right)$

Tags: convergence-divergence

$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}\left(\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{n}\right)$
Can you show me the work for this question

Comment: can i see your attempt? Anything you tried or attempted?

Comment: I wasn't sure where to start. I know it diverges by the nth term test but I wasn't sure how to show the work. The limit just confused me.

Answer (score 3):

Multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}+\sqrt{n}$. You will see that the terms do not approach $0$, so the series diverges.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}} -\sqrt{n}= \sqrt{n}\left[\sqrt{1+\frac 1{\sqrt{n}}}-1\right]
\\
\sim \sqrt{n}\frac 1{2\sqrt{n}} = \frac 12
$$
hence the series is divergent, the partial sum being $\simeq \frac n2$

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the integral of:

$$
\int \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x}} dx
$$

or even multiply 1, expressed as:

$$
\sqrt{n + \sqrt{n}}  + \sqrt{n}
$$

and look where this series goes.